# UDP Broadcast, Multicast, or Unicast for a "Toy Application"

Tags: udp, ip, multicast

I'm looking to write a toy application for my own personal use (and possibly to share with friends) for peer-to-peer shared status on a local network. For instance, let's say I wanted to implement it for the name of the current building you're in (let's pretend the network topology is weird, and multiple buildings occupy the same LAN). The idea is if you run the application, you can set what building you're in, and you can see the buildings of every other user running the application on the local network.

**The question is, what's the best transport/network layer technology to use to implement this?**

My initial inclination was to use UDP Multicast, but the more research I do about it, the more I'm scared off by it: while the technology is great and seems easy to use, if the application is not tailored for a particular site deployment, it also seems most likely to get you a visit from an angry network admin.

I'm wondering, therefore, since this is a relatively low bandwidth application — probably max one update every 4–5 minutes or so from each client, with likely no more than 25–50 clients — whether it might be "cheaper" in many ways to use another strategy:

- **Multicast**: find a way to pick a well-known multicast address from 239.255/16 and have interested applications join the group when they start up.
- **Broadcast**: send out a single UDP Broadcast message every time someone's status changes (and one "refresh" broadcast when the app launches, after which every client replies directly to the requesting user with their current status).
- **Unicast**: send a UDP Broadcast at application start to announce interest, and when a client's status changes, it sends a UDP packet directly to every client who has announced. This results in the highest traffic, but might be less likely to annoy other systems with needless broadcast packets. It also introduces potential complications when apps crash (in terms of generating unnecessary traffic).

Multicast is most certainly the best technology for the job, but I'm wondering if the associated hassles are worth avoiding since this is just a "toy application," not a business-critical service intended for professional network admin deployment and configuration.